# Is there a smbuser file in macOS?

Tags: macos, smb, authentication, cifs

Is there an equivalent configuration file on macOS like the `/etc/samba/smbusers` file on Linux/Unix?

I might be wrong, but I thought the smbusers concept was "a thing" on previous versions of macOS. Such that, the credentials for SMB login are not the same credentials that the User would use to login to their computer.

The goal is to mount a macOS directory (from inside the User's home directory) onto a Windows box.

I am interested specifically in Mojave (10.14) and Catalina (10.15).

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can‘t you just use the credentials of the user?

Comment: As far as I know, it just uses the same accounts as for local login. Note that macOS doesn't use Samba, for licensing reasons; Apple replaced it with a proprietary implementation of SMB starting in version 10.7.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, RE: "Apple replaced it with a proprietary implementation of SMB starting in version 10.7." -- I totally forgot about that, and in looking at samba on **macOS** vs. **Linux Mint**... **macOS** has just these... smbd, smbdiagnose, smbutil while **Linux Mint** has... samba, samba_dnsupdate, smbcacls, samba_downgrade_db, smbclient, samba-gpupdate, smbcontrol, samba_kcc, smbcquotas, samba-regedit, smbd, samba_spnupdate, smbget, samba-tool, smbinfo, samba_upgradedns, smbpasswd, smbspool, smbstatus, smbtar, smbtree. Do you know if the e.g. Samba 4.14.6 can be installed on **macOS**?

Comment: @user3439894 I haven't used it, but it's available via both [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/samba#default) and [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/samba4/) (though MacPorts only has v4.13.1 at this time).

Comment: I'll keep looking in the standard macOS built-in places due to Apple's implementation being proprietary, these days.